# Disqualify some elements and isolate trailing number from array of strings

Tags: php, regex, string, filtering, text-extraction

I have various values in a PHP array, that look like below:

```
$values = ["news_24", "news_81", "blog_56", "member_55", "news_27"];
```

The first part before the underscore (*news, blog, member*) is dynamic so I would like to get all the matches in a specific section (*news*) followed by the numbers.

Something like below:

```
$section = "news";
$matches = preg_match('$section/[_])GETNUMBER/', $values);
```

The solution should return 24, 81, and 27, because only these numbers occurred after `news` and the underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = array("news_24", "news_81", "blog_56", "member_55", "news_27");

$section = "news"; 
foreach($values as $value) {
    $matches = preg_match("/{$section}_(\\d+)/", $value, $number);
    if ($matches)
        echo $number[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array("news_24", "news_81", "blog_56", "member_55", "news_27");

function func($type){
    $results = null;
    foreach($values as $val){
        $curr = explode('_',$val);
        if($curr[0]==$type){
            $results[] = $curr[1];
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$News = func('news');
```

Good luck! :P

Answer (score 0):

Note I added two cases:

```
$values = array ("news_24", "news_81", "blog_56", "member_55", "news_27",
                 "blognews_99", "news_2012_12");

$section = "news";

preg_match_all("/^{$section}_(\\d+)\$/m", implode("\n", $values), $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

The implode might not be super efficient, but it's less code.
The difference is in the matching & regex.

This solution only outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 81
    [2] => 27
)
```

While the others also output 2012 and the solution of Mark also 99.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a native function for this exact task: `preg_filter()`. It attempts to make replacements upon all elements in the array and only returns elements where a successful mutation has occurred.

Match the variably-fed section word, then the literal underscore, then capture the trailing digits.  Replace the whole string with the captured digits.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mso4r))

```
$section = 'news';
var_export(
    preg_filter("/{$section}_(\d+)/", '\1', $array)
);
```

Input:

```
$array = [
    "news_24",
    "news_81",
    "blog_56",
    "member_55",
    "news_27"
];
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '24',
  1 => '81',
  4 => '27',
)
```